# How do I capture instant message traffic on an Android?

Tags: java, android, android-service, instant-messaging

I would like an application that can be downloaded from the market and runs as a service capturing and archiving the following traffic on Android devices: Facebook Messenger, Twitter, Google Talk, MSN, AOL and Yahoo IM.

Is there a way to do this without rooting the phone or developing a custom ROM?

Comment: Yes it would need to be rooted or running a custom rom.

Answer (score 3):

Since the messages are not publicly announced by the apps themselves you would need to capture the network traffic & try to read the information out of there. But it might be  impossible if the apps transfer their messages encrypted (https etc).

Packetcapture either requires root & `tcpdump` (or similar) on the device or Android 4+ and a VPN service like done in [tPacketCapture](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1578974)

I don't believe that packet capture via VPN service is intended to be possible so that might be blocked again in future versions of Android.

> How do I capture instant message traffic on an Android?

So basically you can't do that in a standard app unless the messenger apps provide an API to do so.